# How do I design a handle/identifier for elements inside std::multimap

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, handle, multimap

We are using multimap to store information internally and we want to return a handle to the outside component for future release/removal.

What's the best way to design it? So it is small and fast?

Comment: A class wrapping multimap::iterator, perhaps?

Comment: is the iterator persistent/static? Will it be invalid if the map changes?

Comment: No - in associative containers, an iterator is only invalidated when the element it points to is removed (unlike, say, `std::vector` where inserting or removing one element may invalidate iterators to many others).

Comment: Great! it is the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class wrapping `multimap::iterator` is the answer as Igor Tandetnik pointed out in the comment